Threshold percentage for power ratings of resistors?
So my textbook says always to use a higher power rating resistor than what the max power that resistor is expected to dissipate, which totally makes sense so the resistor doesn't blow. For example, if the max expected power through a resistor is 200 mW, then use a 1/4 W resistor. But what if the max expected power was something like 249 or 249.9 mW? Would a 1/4 W resistor still be appropriate? If not, what would the max expected power through a 1/4 W resistor have to be to stay safe? In general, is there a threshold percentage for resistor power ratings that is the standard or is best practice?

I aim for <= 50% rating, as Neil_UK suggests, unless there is good reason to push limits. If there is a good reason to want to be closer to the full rating you need to do a comprehensive analysis. --> Cooling - what does the datasheet suggest and how does this apply in your case. PCB copper / heatsink / air flow/ max ambient ever going to be experienced / proximity to other components. Also brand of resistor and reputation of manufacturer. I'd be happier running eg Panasonic and once upon a time Philips at close to ratings. Unknown brand, if used at all, not so much.

While the answers to this questions are good, please keep a related point in mind: No matter how high a resistor is rated, the amount of heat produced by it is the same. Resistors rated for higher power either stand higher temperatures and/or are bigger and can radiate the heat to the environment more easily. Nevertheless, you still need to get the heat away somewhere. If you try to dissipate 5W on a resistor in a small plastic case without ventilation, the case will likely overheat, no matter whether you use a 5W, a 10W or a 15W resistor.

The first thing to note is that the power is a rating. That means it's merely specifying the conditions under which the component is measured and warranted.
As you're asking the question, it's perhaps worth you sacrificing a few of your resistors in the cause of education. Taking care not to burn yourself or inhale any fumes, run a few resistors at twice, 10x, and 100x their power rating. How fast do they smoke, catch fire, or de-solder themselves? Measure their value afterwards.
Now that you've got that out of your system, what does a resistor power rating mean? It means that in some specified condition, often 70 C ambient for low power components, sometimes a spot measurement on a lead or higher temperatures for power or military components, that they expect the component to last some defined time in thousands of hours before it fails in some way, usually value drift.
As we rarely control the ambient directly, and as we often make systems containing many resistors, the values of some of which can sometimes be critical, and as resistors are cheap, and as we don't want to do temperature rise sums for all of them, we derate them. This means that if we run well below their rating, we can just throw them at the circuit without any further calculations. The company I used to work for insisted on running resistors at less than 50% of their rated power. Whatever other problems we had in production that we had to solve, overheating resistors was never one of them.

Two of the first things my father taught me, 50 years ago:
When you run a component at its rated power, that is just below the level at which it catches on fire. An exaggeration, but a good thought to keep in your mind.
When margin is cheap, put in a lot.
So, how hot will the resistor get? You can derive the temperature rise from the derating curve. The temperature of this resistor will rise 85 degrees C at its rated power. If your ambient is 25 C, then the resistor will be 110 C! At 50% derating, the temperature will be 67 C, much more reasonable. Still hot, but it won't burn you if you accidentally touch it.

https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/app/datasheet/lr/yageo-mfr_datasheet.pdf
50% derating will keep most components below the human burn temperature. This is my best practice for power ratings.
Components will have a shorter life when run near their maximum power. How much shorter is complicated (we had a dedicated reliability engineer to run the calculations). But for common components, we generally had to keep our components under 100 C to meet our reliability requirements.
Wire-wound resistors are designed to run hotter, check the datasheet. They may still burn you even at 50% derating.
If you are a hobbyist building one unit, then err on the conservative side. If this is an industrial design and you are building hundreds, the extra analysis may cost more than the few cents to buy a higher rated part.

Ratings are kind of a general guide to what is sensible for a part. For example, take Yageo's leaded metal film resistor datasheet.

This tells you that if the ambient temperature is greater than 70°C you must derate the resistor, all the way down to zero at 155°C. So if the ambient is actually 100°C full rating of a '250mW resistor' is only about 160mW.
Note that they don't suggest you can get more than 250mW dissipation if you limit the Ta to less than 70°C, though that's probably true (not that I would recommend it).
So there are a few reasons why we might want to derate a resistor under nominal operating conditions.

To avoid a really hot part- so it doesn't degrade your circuit board etc. If it's part of a measuring circuit you might want to minimize thermal shift.

To account for tolerances in your design or in what a user might do to it. Maybe your circuit is designed for mains voltage but someone, somewhere, someday is going to use it  in a poorly regulated application where the mains is high by 20% and it's a 50°C day in an uncooled location.

To account for pulsed operation (this is a complex area and not all parts have adequate information supplied to evaluate reliability under pulsed conditions).

For reliability. All other things being equal, a part that runs cooler will typically last longer.

To minimize shift in value- Yageo considers a 0.5% resistor that shifts ±1.5%+0.05Ω during operation at 70°C as acceptable. Maybe you would like to do better than that.


Some downsides are

Cost - a 2512 resistor might cost 10x or 15x as much as an 0603

Size - PCB area

Availability


When it comes to surface mount parts, the mounting and surrounding copper etc. has a large effect on thermal characteristics. This is pretty complex to evaluate so we tend to err on the side of being conservative.
As far as a general rule of thumb, I would say at least derating to 60%, but that might vary a bit depending on the application. If it's just a dropping resistor for a power-on LED, nobody cares if it shifts in value by 3% and even if it quits entirely the device will continue to operate. If it's in a measuring circuit where accuracy is fundamental to the device's function, that's another matter.

I generally try to derate by at least 20%, up to 50% if SWaP-C supports it. Sometimes this isn't possible and then you have to do a more detailed analysis of the worst case conditions, failure modes, etc. With other components like e.g. ceramic caps where voltage even at 80% of maximum can cause undesirable effects, then even more analysis is required. For resistors, the temperature coefficient of resistance might also be significant if you are close to the power limit; the operating temperature of a ribwound resistor can be several hundred C over ambient.

Okay. So just to be clear - capacitors are not rated by power, but voltage? Also, is it still safe to have a resistor such as a ribwound resistor to be operating at such high temperatures like you described? And what do you mean by "failure modes"? I'm curious.

@polimorphism Resistors, capacitors and inductors have energy, power, current and voltage ratings -- which ones apply to a given situation, or how to even determine them from ratings -- or if the datasheet gives those ratings at all -- is another matter, unfortunately; but it is safe to assume the limits exist.

An old ham radio handbook I read decades ago contained an interesting recipe of a 200 watt, 50 ohm resistor for testing RF tarnsmitter amplifiers:
A 50 ohm, 2 watt resistor immersed in a glass of cold water.
This actually works, provided you change the water in the glass before it starts to boil. If one knows what they are doing, dumping 100x the rated power over a resistor can (sort of) work.
When extreme cooling methods are not available, one trades between cost, volume, reliability and safety.
The resistor rating is something like a spherical cow in vacuum. It assumes some ideal-ish conditions and what's worse, these conditions somewhat vary between vendors.
That said, an 1/4W resistor will probably be good at 240mW, 250mW, maybe even 400mW - for a while. A sane engineer will not do things like these.
If you are not profoundly constrained in budget, space, regulations or extreme reliability requirements, you simply derate. You put 1/4 instead of 1/8W for 100mW real and hope that everything goes well.
Otherwise, it's complicated.

It works fine even when the water starts boiling. Evaporative cooling is really powerful.

In this particular case, boiling does not really help. The first steam bubbles create hot spots and if you are quick to turn off the power you can see the brown circles over the resistor surface.

Yes, granted, a hundredfold overload is brutal. With a tenfold it would probably be OK.
